# Debugging - Reduce audio microphone input level in Swift 4.2 - it is too sensitive

Tags: swift, avaudiosession

I am trying to measure ambient noise near the phone - like having a sound meter at a live event.  I need a means to normalize the sound meter so it is not 100% most of the time.

I am using the code below - where it works - but the input microphone level is too high or too sensitive - how can I reduce the input level or sensitivity

```
var player: AVAudioPlayer?
var isFromMVP : Bool = false
var mvpSnapshot : DataSnapshot!
var currentRatio : CGFloat = 0.0

var timerAudioD: DispatchSourceTimer?
var _peak = 0.0
var _average = 0.0
let DATADOG_KEY = "YOUR_KEY_HERE"
var audioLevelTimer: Timer = Timer()

// Dave added imgAudio and viewAudio to show decibles
@IBOutlet weak var viewAudio: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var imgAudio: UIImageView!

@objc func audioLevelRefresh ()
{
   // print ("Volume: ", _average, " - ", _peak)
    var ratio = CGFloat (_average - 50.0) / 50.0
    var x = CGFloat (0.0)
    var y = CGFloat (0.0)
    var w = CGFloat (viewAudio.frame.width) * ratio
    var h = CGFloat (viewAudio.frame.height)

    if (CameSelectionTableViewCell.IsHomeSelected)
    {
        imgAudio.frame = CGRect (x: viewAudio.frame.width - w + x, y: y, width: w, height: h);
    }
    else{ // away is cheered for}
        imgAudio.frame = CGRect (x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h);
    }
}
func SetupAudioMeter ()
{
    timerAcceleration = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(0.1), target: self, selector: #selector(showAudio), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
// dave - change microphone sensitivity
func setInputGain(gain: Float) {
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    if audioSession.isInputGainSettable {
        var error : NSErrorPointer = nil

        let success = try? audioSession.setInputGain(gain)

        guard let s = success else {
            print ("audio error")
            return
        }
        if (success != nil) {
            print("\(error)")
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Cannot set input gain")
    }
}
func recordDatapoint(average: Float, peak: Float) {
    // Send a single datapoint to DataDog
    let datadogUrlString = "https://app.datadoghq.com/api/v1/series?api_key=\(DATADOG_KEY)"

    _peak = Double(peak)
    _average = Double(average)

    let deviceName = UIDevice.current.name
    let timestamp = (NSInteger)(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
    let body = [
        "series": [
            ["metric": "office.dblevel.average", "host": deviceName, "points": [ [timestamp, average] ] ],
            ["metric": "office.dblevel.peak", "host": deviceName, "points":[ [timestamp, peak] ] ],
        ]
    ]
}
// dave added for audiometer
func recordForever(audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder) {
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "io.segment.decibel", attributes: .concurrent)
    timerAudioD = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(flags: [], queue: queue)
    timerAudioD?.schedule(deadline: .now(), repeating: 0.1, leeway: .milliseconds(100))

    setInputGain(gain: 1)

    timerAudioD?.setEventHandler { [weak self] in
        audioRecorder.updateMeters()

        // NOTE: seems to be the approx correction to get real decibels
        let correction: Float = 100
        let average = audioRecorder.averagePower(forChannel: 0) + correction
        let peak = audioRecorder.peakPower(forChannel: 0) + correction
        self?.recordDatapoint(average: average, peak: peak)
    }

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        timerAudioD?.activate()
    } else {
        timerAudioD?.resume()
    }
}
func directoryURL() -> URL? {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let urls = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentDirectory = urls[0] as URL
    let soundURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("sound.m4a")
    return soundURL
}
func setupAudioMeter()
{
    guard let url = directoryURL() else {
        print("Unable to find a init directoryURL")
        return
    }
    let recordSettings = [
        AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(value: Float(44100.0) as Float),
        AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(value: Int32(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC) as Int32),
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(value: 1 as Int32),
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : NSNumber(value: Int32(AVAudioQuality.medium.rawValue) as Int32),
        ]


    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.spokenAudio, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions())  // (category: AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: )
        let audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: url, settings: recordSettings)

        // dave adding volume control
        //let success = try? audioSession.setInputGain (0.1)

        audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
        audioRecorder.record()
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
        audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
        let audioSession2 = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance ()

        recordForever(audioRecorder: audioRecorder)

        if audioSession2.isInputGainSettable{
            var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
            do{
                let success = try? audioSession2.setInputGain (0.1)//, error: error)
                if ((success) != nil){
                    print ("\(error)")
                }
            }
            catch{ print ("cannot set input gain!!!") }
        }else{
            print ("cannot set input gain")
        }


        print("started recording")
    } catch let err {
        print("Unable start recording", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm facing the same problem